# How do I properly setup TXT records for letsencrypt with Namecheap?

Tags: domain-name-system, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to use the [manuale](https://github.com/veeti/manuale) application to register my domains with Letsencrypt, but I'm running into this problem:

```
urn:acme:error:connection
```

Here's how I'm running it:

```
⚘ manuale authorize home.waynewerner.com waynewerner.com
Requesting challenge for home.waynewerner.com.
Requesting challenge for waynewerner.com.
DNS verification required. Make sure these TXT records are in place:
  _acme-challenge.waynewerner.com.  IN TXT  "<Some key>"
  _acme-challenge.home.waynewerner.com.  IN TXT  "<some other key>"
```

So I signed into my namecheap dashboard and in my host records I added two new TXT records. In the host field I tried it both ways, with `@` and `home` and with `_acme-challenge.waynewerner.com` and `_acme-challenge.home.waynewerner.com`. Then the value fields contained `<Some key>` and `<some other key>` (without quotes).

And yet I still get:

```
home.waynewerner.com: waiting for verification. Checking in 5 seconds.
home.waynewerner.com: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.home.waynewerner.com (urn:acme:error:connection)
waynewerner.com: waiting for verification. Checking in 5 seconds.
waynewerner.com: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up TXT for _acme-challenge.waynewerner.com (urn:acme:error:connection)
0 domain(s) authorized, 2 failed.
Authorized: N/A
Failed: home.waynewerner.com waynewerner.com
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've verified that if I use the `@` and `home` hosts then

```
dig -t txt home.waynewerner.com
dig -t txt waynewerner.com
```

both provide the keys that I set in my DNS.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using TXT record based verification rather than web request based?

Comment: @Tim I'm using salt to manage my servers but the formula for letsencrypt failed. I may change to the web request based version later, but for now I wanted to get a feel for what things were actually doing. Do you know if I have to update my DNS records when I renew my certificates?

Comment: I used a piece of free software called ACME that was really easy. My knowledge beyond that is limited in this area. https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/

Comment: also, I really like the snark in the manuale documentation ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your dig checks aren't checking the right thing. LetsEncrypt is actually looking for records called `_acme-challenge.domain.com`.  I'm not sure how namecheap's DNS interface works. But you need to create records that respond to the following dig queries.

```
dig -t txt _acme-challenge.home.waynewerner.com
dig -t txt _acme-challenge.waynewerner.com
```

Comment: The host fields had to be `_acme-challenge` and `_acme-challenge.home`. If I wanted `www.waynewerner.com` presumably I'd also have to add `_acme-challenge.www`

Comment: yes, the "host" value must only be _acme-challenge, no domain suffix needed!